# Symfony2 Failed to start the session: already started by PHP

Tags: php, symfony, session

i got a very strange issue looking like this:

```
[2014-11-06 11:21:13] request.INFO: Matched route "core_timetracking_new_user" (parameters: "_controller": "Bricks\Custom\CoreBundle\Controller\TimeTrackingController::newuserAction", "_route": "core_timetracking_new_user") [] []
[2014-11-06 11:21:13] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP." at /var/cache/app/prod/classes.php line 113 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException: Failed to start the session: already started by PHP. at /var/cache/app/prod/classes.php:113)"} []
```

the strange thing is i do not start a session or use it, heres the Controller code:

```
/**
 * @View
 */
public function newuserAction()
{
    $trackingService=$this->get('core.timetracking_service');
    $user= new TimeTrackingUser();
    $request=$this->getRequest();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('email','text')
        ->add('pass','password')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Erstellen'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $trackingService->persistUser($form->getData());
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('core_timetracking_user_list'));
    }else {
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );
    }
}
```

while this action works wonderfull

```
/**
 * @View
 */
public function listuserAction()
{

    $request=$this->getRequest();
    $trackingService=$this->get('core.timetracking_service');    
    $users=$trackingService->getAllUsers();

    return array(
        'users' => $users
    );
}
```

so the only difference is that i use

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

also checked if all my files AppKernel etc do start with

both actions ( the working one and the not working one ) are in the same controller

Comment: Do you happen to have the "session.auto_start" configuration option turned on? http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

Comment: Hi @john Smith,Session is auto stated by Symfony2,so it might be possible,if you manually start  session again using PHP function or other way, it might be possible to occurred that problem, and you can stop auto start session in config.yml file.

Comment: @Erik session.auto_start => Off => Off  , it seems to be off

Comment: also the second action also works when calling $request=$this->getRequest(); there, i just dont get the error, it seems $form->handleRequest is involved

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you render a form, Symfony automatically starts a session to store the token for CSRF Protection:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

You can disable CSRF Protection, but it's on by default.

**@rakete:**
The only additional idea I have is to change the way in which session files are stored (e.g. file system, database, memory, etc.). See here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html

Comment: Is there no alternative to disabling the protection? I had the same problem and solved it by disabling it - but I think that is not the best solution...

Comment: I would guess *NO*. Symfony needs to save the CSRF token somewhere, and the only way to preserve it over two requests is the session. Why is it so important for you to prevent the session from being started?

Comment: @rakete unfortunatly its some time ago and i cant remeber but it may be that wejust wondered and left the token disabled, now when i read this i really wonder because i never ran into the same problem in any symfony project afterwards

Answer (score 0):

**You should check if you have any listener who start a new session.**

You mustn't have a listener with a `new Session()`. You should use the request session as in the action methods.

---

I have a onKernelController listener who started a new session with `new Session()` and then when the form try to make the csrf token it checks if a session exists and throw the exception.